# How can I insert a video from Google Photos into an email using Gmail?

Tags: gmail, google-photos

Composing an email in Gmail, I can insert photos from Google Photos as attachments or links easily.
But videos in my Google Photos account do not show in the list of media... is there a way to share a video in an email as easily as a photo?

Answer (score -2):

When you have your email open, look at the bottom of your settings bar. On the right-hand side, there should be a button called "Insert Photo". After clicking on that, there should be a heading called "Google Photos".

Comment: as I said, this only shows photos not videos for some reason.